# ICC in psych package: Error in stack.data.frame(x) : no vector columns were selected

Tags: r, icc, psych

I am trying to calculate the ICC using ICC in the psych package. I have scans, which 3 raters measured (rater C, L, N below). I think I formatted my matrix incorrectly.

My code:

```
data=read.csv("SLICER_FAINT_ICC.csv")
label(data$Scan)="CT Scan"
label(data$Rater.C)="C"
label(data$Rater.L)="L"
label(data$Rater.N)="N"
x<-as.matrix(data)
ICC(x)`
```

The error:
`Error in stack.data.frame(x) : no vector columns were selected`

My matrix looks like this:

```
    print(x)
       Scan      Rater.C    Rater.L    Rater.N   
  `[1,] "FA001FU" "1202.450" "1136.550" "1138.860"`
  `[2,] "﻿FA001IN" "1152.660" "1119.520" "1094.260"` 
  `[3,] "﻿FA002FU" "1209.220" "1102.660" "1149.670"`
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you use `dput()` on your `data` variable and post the results so that we can see exactly how `data` is structured and replicate your issue more easily?

Comment: Could you edit this to show any other libraries/packages you have loaded?  If you run `library()$results[,1]` it will show all the libraries you have loaded.

Comment: ```#Load packages:
library(tidyverse)
library(Hmisc)
library(ggplot2)
library(matrixStats)
library(devtools)
library(LaCroixColoR)
library(ggplot2)
library(magick)
library(magrittr) 
library(curl)
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)
library(psych)```

Comment: I removed some of the entries to make this fit in a comment, but: ```> dput(data)
structure(list(Scan = structure(1:124, .Label = c("FA001FU", 
"FA001IN", "FA002FU", "FA002IN"...
"FA494IN", "FA509FU", "FA509IN"), class = c("labelled", 
"factor"), label = "CT Scan"), Rater.C = structure(c(1202.45,...), label = "Nathan", class = c("labelled", "numeric"))), row.names = c(NA, -124L), class = "data.frame")```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ICC()` is expecting a matrix of all numbers, but when you include the text column `Scan` in the matrix and since a matrix can only have one variable type, it converts all the values to strings.

Remove the column Scans and then it should work.  Here's an example with the relevant code:

```
#remove the Scan column
data$Scan<-NULL

#now this should work
x<-as.matrix(data)
ICC(x)
```